# App remove from recent history event

Tags: android

I want to log out the user when the app is removed from recent history. I googled, But cant find any possible solution.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code for logout in `OnStop()` method of your `Activity`.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Your code for implementing logout
    }
```

Comment: `onDestroy` will be better candidate as @Gunaseelan want to logout user when app is removed from history

Answer (score 0):

Following method is called when app is removed from recent stack.

`@Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    Log.e("onDetachedFromWindow", "activity dying");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

When the app is removed from the recent history, the Android OS kills the VM that is running the app. That means that every variable in memory will get destroyed.

Said that, all you have to do is to not save the login details anywhere.

For example:

```
// some flag marking the user is logged in
public static boolean isLoggedIn = false;

// whenever the user logins appropriately
isLoggedIn = true;

// then through the app check it
if(isLoggedIn) .. do stuff
```

when the VM get's kille the `true` value will be lost and next time it will be false again.